# Нужна ли запятая перед "и не обязательно за один день"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Их можно получать из разных продуктов и не обязательно за один день". Не является ли фраза после "и" присоединительной конструкцией?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе здесь возможны варианты, то есть союз И можно считать соединительным (запятая не ставится) или присоединительным (запятая ставится). Выбор, в частности, может зависеть от контекста, то есть от того, как предложение вписывается в общую структуру текста.

Если контекст не учитывать, то мне присоединительный вариант кажется более предпочтительным: ***Их можно получать из разных продуктов, и не обязательно за один день.***

По семантике он подходит, то есть можно использовать присоединительный союз "причем". Также желательно сделать паузу перед союзом И, так как  произношение  без подчеркнутой паузы менее удобно и выразительно. В этом случае мы как бы делим информацию на две части, удобные для восприятия.